# PackageMaker integrated into XCode without a temporary directory

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, environment-variables, packagemaker

I currently have a target in XCode which calls 'packagemaker' command line tool from a script, and am able to run this without any problems. However I can't figure out how to set the paths inside my .pmdoc file. The only way I got it to work is by having post-build steps to copy to a temporary directory for each target whose binary is consumer by the installer, and then my paths in the .pmdoc file are hardcoded to the temporary directory.

I was hoping I could use environment variables in the .pmdoc path entries, but they don't seem to be supported.

Am I stuck having to copy everything to a temporary dir, or is there any other way to clean things up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packagemaker also is a non GUI terminal tool. So you can write shell script which will be take pathes, variables... as arguments and build pkg file. More detail information you can see in the [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/packagemaker/).

Comment: Yes, the command line tool you mention is what I was referring to in my question. I have that working against a .pmdoc file with hardcoded paths, but was not able to figure out to use environment variables in stead of hardcoded paths.

Comment: No, I mean that you can fully replace pmdoc file with a shell scripts. So you pkg file will be builds dynamically using you scripts and env variables